# CSS positioning not working

Tags: html, css

Sometimes I have observed that the CSS positioning property does not work expectedly. Below is my code,

```
.position
{
position:absolute;
left:50%;
}
```

The above code should position the element of the class at 50% of the screen, but it is not happening. To position it in required place I have to write 'left:220%' what could be the reason of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example of 'it not working'?

Comment: No one said it'd be at 50% of the screen - it'll be at 50% of the next applicable parent element

Comment: Yes, as @Pekka said, it is 50% of the closest parent or element with "position:relative" Think of "position:relative" as an anchor for the next "position:absolute". The code you pasted is correct in sending the element to 50% of the parent with relative positioning. For 50% of the screen, you want "position:fixed"

Comment: @Pekka웃 but isn't that in case when I specify the position as 'relative'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements with `position: relative` and `position: absolute` are relative not to the screen (or rather, the current document), but to the *next parent element* with `position: relative` or `position: absolute` set.

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjPXv/7/) illustrating the issue.

[image]

You have no way to "break out" of that prison with pure CSS. To position the element relative to the document, you should make it a direct child of the document.

Comment: I found that only 10% area of my textbox is clickable. And the other elements are just neglecting the rest 90% of the textbox and are positioning themselves considering only that 10% part of the textbox. ANy pointers on this weird situation?

Comment: @Yogi I'm not 100% sure what is going on, but it may be a z-index issue. Can you show a JSfiddle?

Comment: Hey thanks bud, I worked a little harder on your concept of 'breaking out of the prison' and it seems to be working great. Thanks for your help.